# Tag hint-box hidden behind the main review edit dialog

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, suggested-edits, tooltips

When reviewing an edit on the post's page, when you hover any tag, the `Hint-box` 
 (i.e. an absolutely positioned element containing `<div id="tag-menu">...</div>`) hides behind the main review edit dialog. Like:
[image]

This is for every tag on every post. I believe this needs fixing.